# jq - set a value to another value conditionally

Tags: json, jq

I need to set the value of a field in a json doc to one of three values using jq, depending on which exists. Notionally this looks like: `set X to (if A exists, else if B exists, else if C exists, else "")`.

An example json doc I have looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "0230",
  "publish_date": "2007-08-18",
  "abc_severity": "",
  "def_severity": "medium",
  "ghi_severity": "negligible"
}
```

I would like to create a field `Severity` and set it's value to the value of `abc_severity` not null or empty. if it is null or empty I would like to set it to `def_severity`, and if that's null or empty I would like to set it to `ghi_severity`. If all three are null or empty is may be created with an empty value `""`. So the output in this case would be:

```
{
  "name": "0230",
  "publish_date": "2007-08-18",
  "abc_severity": "",
  "def_severity": "medium",
  "ghi_severity": "negligible",
  "Severity": "medium"
}
```

The following is the closest I seem to be able to get:

`'. | if .abc_severity? then .Severity=.abc_severity else if .def_severity? then .Severity=.def_severity else if .ghi_severity? then .Severity=.ghi_severity else .Severity="" end end end'`

But the value of `Severity` is always `""` even if one or more of the other values exist. I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple here, I just can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An empty string is still a string, so `.abc_severity?` would give you an empty string, not `null` (or `false`). Also, note that the question mark means approximately "replace with `null` if this key does not exist".  In the example, all three keys exist, and their values are not `null`.

If you had been using `null` for empty values, your `jq` expression would have looked like

```
.Severity = (.abc_severity // .def_severity // .ghi_severity )
```

The above expression would have picked the first of the three values that weren't `null`, testing the left-most first and going right, or `null` if all of them were `null`. But that won't work now as we have to deal with empty strings *as if* they were `null`.

We can do that by introducing a helper function (to reduce our typing a bit):

```
def n: if . == "" then null else . end;
.Severity = ((.abc_severity|n) // (.def_severity|n) // (.ghi_severity|n) // "")
```

Our helper function `n` returns the string as-is if it is not empty; otherwise, it returns `null`.  With chained `//` operators, we pick the first value of the three that is not `null`, when seen through `n`, or the empty string if all three values are `null`.

Testing the above on the command line with your data:

```bsh
$ jq 'def n: if . == "" then null else . end; .Severity = ((.abc_severity|n) // (.def_severity|n) // (.ghi_severity|n) // "")' file
{
  "name": "0230",
  "publish_date": "2007-08-18",
  "abc_severity": "",
  "def_severity": "medium",
  "ghi_severity": "negligible",
  "Severity": "medium"
}
```